# External hard disk is not loading

Tags: external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

I have a Sony 1TB Hard disk, which has been working fine for a year. The Hard disk is powered by a USB cable. It had 300 GB free space.

Now when I connect my HD, my Windows keeps loading it and all I can see is the Hard disk symbol in 'My computer' window without my Hard disk name in it (Normally it used to show my HD name and available capacity in it but now its just Disk symbol) and I am unable to access it as the window is loading indefinitely.

I tried running `chkdsk /F` and `chkdsk /R` but nothing is happening.

Could someone please suggest a solution. I have very important data on it.

I don't know whether it might be helpful but for your info; Recently I had a folder accessing problem in Hard Disk `not accessible: Data Cyclic redundancy error` for a particular folder in the HD. I ran `chkdsk /f` two times and both time the Prompt ran too much time (a whole day).

Comment: Is there anything you tried to solve it?

Comment: Hmmm yes i tried chkdsk command and it ran 2 complete days.. Then even im facing that issue..

Comment: Are there any entries in your system event log when you run chkdsk (from source NTFS or DISK)?

Comment: I tried check disk two weeks before now i couldn't able to find entries in sys logs

Comment: Probably it's broken. As last chance you can try to connect the disk directly to internal sata connector in the pc. To do this you have to disasseble the case of your external hdd and extract the disk. If issue is usb related, in this way you can restore the data.

Comment: I tried with different windows machine and used other usb cables too.. My guess..Whether it might be problem with the windows machine ?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds to me like your hard disk is dead or dying.

The symptoms you are describing could be a locked hard disk arm.

Have you experienced a power failure of the PC, while the disk was connected? Or perhaps had the hard disk unplugged from the PC without first stopping it using the "Safely Remove Hardware" icon in the Task bar?

I would try the following (in the order written):

- connect the hard disk to another PC to check if it's a driver / PC problem
- replace the USB cable and try with a new cable to check for defective cable
- use a Linux Live CD to see if you can get the drive working under a different OS.

If these methods do not work:

- remove the Hard drive from the external case and see if you can plug it into a PC using a SATA cable (requires some experience with hardware).
- have a professional technician inspect the drive and do problem solving/repair

If you still are getting no results:

- I would try, **as an absolutely final option** (also see comment by user "Xen2050" below), to open up the hard drive and see if you can move the hard disk arm to the "parking position" (i.e. off of the disk) and see if that helps (requires **a lot** of experience with hardware repair).

Comment: Yes few times have unplugged directly .. Right now i don't have Linux machine .. Will try and reply in the same post as earlier.. Just for the info, After running chkdsk , harddrive opened for two or three times ..

Comment: It is really bad for the disk to be unplugged directly, *especially* if the drive is working (i.e. reading/writing) when you unplug it. This can cause the hard drive arm to get stuck out of the parking position, which can cause the malfunction you are describing.

Comment: Okie..thanks.. And if i connect to system, the led light blinks for couple of minutes and it gets turned off but in the drive list i can see the hdd but with no operations performed from dat

Comment: The LED blinking means at least the disk is getting power from the USB cable. So you should probably investigate other options. The symptoms you are describing indicates that the hardware in the external case is working, but the actual hard disk can't read, so Windows cant determine the drive label (name), capacity etc. This would be an indication that the drive has failed or the arm is stuck (as mentioned in my answer).

Comment: Do NOT open the actual hard drive - so you can see the platters & arm(s) - **until you've tried every other software & direct connection option first**.  Especially try data recovery tools like `gddrescue` and `testdisk`/`photorec` in linux. Just opening the lid & putting it back could throw something off so it never reads again

Comment: Here's a quick guide on HD data recovery, even if some sectors won't read & you can't mount it in Windows, you might still be able to read most of your data. The idea is: raw copy everything you can now (before the drive gets any worse) then recover from your copy... Any more writes or attempting `chkdsk` for 24hrs could cause more damage https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery#Imaging_a_damaged_device.2C_filesystem_or_drive or

Comment: Getting the following error.. E:/ is not accessible.. The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.. Where E:/ external hdd